# CKEditor5 setup 'Cannot read property 'create' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, ckeditor

I'm trying to get CKEditor5 set up on my site using the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic` npm package. I have version 12.0.0 installed which is the latest as of today.

I am using the following setup method - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#scenario-1-integrating-existing-builds which seems like it should be very simple.

I am using TypeScript and have the following code within a module:

```
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('.html-editor'))
    .then(editor => {
        console.log(editor);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

...which is transpiled into the following JavaScript:

```
var ckeditor5_build_classic_1 = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic");
ckeditor5_build_classic_1["default"]
    .create(document.querySelector('.html-editor'))
    .then(function (editor) {
    console.log(editor);
})["catch"](function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Unfortunately I get the following error on the load of the page:

```
addadventure.ts:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (addadventure.ts:11)
    at Object../wwwroot/js/pages/adventures/addadventure.ts (addadventure.ts:266)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Object.1 (addadventure.ts:266)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at bootstrap:857
    at bootstrap:857
```

It knows that `ckeditor5_build_classic_1` is a class but `ckeditor5_build_classic_1["default"]` is undefined.

**EDIT:**

Curiously, if I put a breakpoint on the line it fails on and run the following in the console, it works...

```
ckeditor5_build_classic_1.create(document.querySelector('.html-editor'))
```

Is it the transpiling that's the problem then?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with this `import` instead?

```
import * as InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set/unset `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` compiler options?